# Excel: Probability That h Heads Will Appear In n Coin Tosses

Tags: excel, statistics, probability

I want to calculate the probability that h number of heads will appear in n coin tosses using Excel. For example, the probability of 4 heads appearing in  5 coin tosses. This is the formula:

```
[n! / h!(n-h)!] * 2^-n
```

How do I convert this into Excel? What I have is:

```
=(FACT($A$2)/FACT(B2)*FACT($A$2-B2))*POWER(2,-$A$2)
```

With A2 representing the number of tosses and B2 the number of heads, but this doesn't seem to work. Well, it works for 4 heads and 5 heads, but that's it. For 0 heads I should be getting 1/32, but instead I get 450. For 1 head I should be getting 5/32, but instead I get 90. I'm really confused. I suspect I'm not multiplying my factorials correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just this should do:

```
=(FACT($A$2)/(FACT(B2)*FACT($A$2-B2))*POWER(2,-$A$2))
```

---

Your formula just needed brackets in the denominator

```
=FACT($A$2)/FACT(B2)*FACT($A$2-B2)
```

doesn't equal

```
=FACT($A$2)/(FACT(B2)*FACT($A$2-B2))
```

if it's easier to read

```
 a/b*c = (a*c)/b --> but you want --> a/(b*c)
```